# Trigger to determine when a field was last populated

Tags: trigger, apex

After extensive research I think I know what I need to do, but I don’t know how to get there

basically, I need to create a trigger to determine when a field was last populated.

I know this can be done via workflow and using the now() function for eg, if field is changed populate with date. However I have over 50 fields per object so don’t want to great 50 new date/time fields.

Now my idea is to Create a new object called “Analysis” and have the following three fields
“Object Name”, “field” , “Last Populated ”. (Not sure whether to use api name or field name)

For eg (If this field was last populated four days ago and  trigger run today)
Object Name = Account
Field Name = Agent Code
Api  Name = Agent_Code__c
Last Populated  =  01/06/2014

For eg (If this field was last today and trigger run today)
Object Name = Account
Field Name = Agent Code
Api  Name = Agent_Code__c
Last Populated  =  05/06/2014

Comment: Do you really need it for all 50 fields ? And, have you looked into field-history-tracking ?

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke History Tracking is only for up to 20 fields, so that may not help in this case, although that'd be my first recommendation, too.

Comment: That is why i asked if he needs 50 fields. I do believe salesforce can increase that limit .. if you have good arguments.

Comment: Hi, 
Field history only for 20 fields, and we have 50 + per object , so enabling field history wouldnt be viable option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an object called AccountHistoryTracking with fields like `APIName__c`, `OldValue__c`, `NewValue__c`, then create a fieldset on Account called 'HistoryTracking' with the fields you want to track on Account, and then write below code to track history on Account:

```
trigger AccountHistoryTracker on Account (after insert,after update) {
    List<Schema.FieldSetMember> trackedFields = SObjectType.Account.FieldSets.HistoryTracking.getFields();
    if (trackedFields.isEmpty()) return;

    List<AccountHistoryTracking__c> fieldChanges = new List<AccountHistoryTracking__c>();

    List<String> apiNameList = new List<String>();        

    if(Trigger.isUpdate){
        for (Account aNew : trigger.new) {

            Account aOld = trigger.oldmap.get(aNew.Id);

            for (Schema.FieldSetMember fsm : trackedFields) {

                String fieldName  = fsm.getFieldPath();
                String fieldLabel = fsm.getLabel();

                if (aNew.get(fieldName) != aOld.get(fieldName)) {

                    String oldValue = String.valueOf(aOld.get(fieldName));
                    String newValue = String.valueOf(aNew.get(fieldName));
                    if (oldValue != null && oldValue.length()>255) oldValue = oldValue.subString(0,255);
                    if (newValue != null && newValue.length()>255) newValue = newValue.subString(0,255); 

                    AccountHistoryTracking__c aht = new AccountHistoryTracking__c();
                    aht.name         = fieldLabel;
                    aht.apiName__c   = fieldName;
                    aht.User__c      = aNew.Id;
                    aht.ChangedBy__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
                    aht.OldValue__c  = oldValue;
                    aht.NewValue__c  = newValue;

                    apiNameList.add(aht.apiName__c);
                    fieldChanges.add(aht);

                }        

            }

        }

        List<AccountHistoryTracking__c> ahtToDelete = [select Id,apiName__c from AccountHistoryTracking__c where apiName__c in:apiNameList];

        if(ahtToDelete.size()>0){
            delete ahtToDelete;
        }
    }

    if(Trigger.isInsert){
        for (Account aNew : trigger.new) {
            for (Schema.FieldSetMember fsm : trackedFields) {

                String fieldName  = fsm.getFieldPath();
                String fieldLabel = fsm.getLabel(); 
                String newValue = String.valueOf(aNew.get(fieldName));
                if (newValue != null && newValue.length()>255) newValue = newValue.subString(0,255); 
                AccountHistoryTracking__c aht = new AccountHistoryTracking__c();
                aht.name         = fieldLabel;
                aht.apiName__c   = fieldName;
                aht.User__c      = aNew.Id;
                aht.ChangedBy__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
                aht.NewValue__c  = newValue;

                apiNameList.add(aht.apiName__c);
                fieldChanges.add(aht);

            }
        }
    }

    if (!fieldChanges.isEmpty()) {
        insert fieldChanges;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sf.Dev
I have a developer org https://login.salesforce.com/?lt=de

I have created the object AccountHistoryTracking
But i am now confused, is it possible if you could log in and have a look ?

Comment: @user8746 have u created fields like apiName__c, User__c, ChangedBy__c, OldValue__c, NewValue__c

Comment: @ Sf dev. I cant sign in into my account when at work, so it registered me as user8746. yes all those fields are created, and the trigger created. However what i have noticed, if  i update any field more than once it it shows in the report.

For eg. i updated website from hotmail to yahoo to google, and i have 3 records . 

I ideally want to see one record. and that be the latest one

Comment: @Masond3 you mean to delete the old field history record and create new field history record everytime field changes

Comment: @sf dev - Yes. i should have one record per field. so if i have 50 fields per object i would expect 50 records in the report

Comment: @Masond3 I just updated the code.Please try it and let me know

Comment: @sf dev- i am now getting required result however, the previous results are still showing in the report ? 

if i want to use this across multiple objects, any idea how this can be done ?

Comment: @Masond3 for previous results please delete records manually.For this to work on multiple objects you need to create trigger for each object .I think you could reuse tracking object to track across all objects but need to change code accordingly.Please mark answer as accepted

Comment: @Masond3 you need to login as user8746 and mark answer as accepted(Below the down vote there is check mark)

Comment: OKay, il be back in work tomorrow, il try and log in then and do it . thanks for all your help

Comment: @ SF.dev So i started testing the logic you provided above, and it the history tracking only seems to be applying to one account. Eg created “Account1” yesterday changed the website field and it shows up in the report the new / old value and date last populated. However created a new account today called “Account”, populated website field and it’s not showing in the report.

Comment: The report is supposed to tell me when the “Website” Field was last populated regardless of the number of accounts there are. So in the scenario above, If I run the report yesterday last modified date = 05/06/14 as I changed the website address on the “account 1”. If no new values were populated in the website field the date would still be 05/06/14. However as “account 2” been created/modified and the website field has been populated today, I would expect the last modified date to say 06/06/14
Does that make sense ?

Comment: @user8746 updated the trigger.please test it and let me know

Comment: @Sf.dev - Problem with that code is that its populating duplicate records. So the field website is now populated twice. I need one record per field with last modifed date, (Therefore Oldvalue / Newvalue) isnt applicable

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 options:

1) Enable field history tracking.

2) Create a trigger that uses the Schema to loop through every field on an object.

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> auditQuestion_map = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('ObjectName__c).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
```

I suggest using option 1, but if for some reason it doesn't fulfill your needs you can fall back on option 2.

EDIT:

Do your normal loop through trigger.new and then inside that another loop over the fields.  This should give you a general basis.

```
List<Tracking_Obj> tracking = new List<Tracking_Obj>();
for (SObject someObj: Trigger.new)
{
  SObject old = Trigger.oldMap.get(someObj.Id);
  for (Schema.SObjectField field: Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('ObjectName__c).getDescribe().fields.getMap())
  {
    //I don't remember the exact syntax, but you can look up the API for that
    if (someObj.get(field.Name) != old.get(field.Name)
      tracking.add(new TrackingObj(Name = field.Name));
  }
}
```

Comment: Dphil 
Can you explain to me how option 2 works ?